# Is it OK to have multiple Access instances running in parallel?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have multiple sets of code I need to run in Access 2007 and I have been trying to see if it would be acceptable to run them at the same time. Each set of data I need to have my Access VBA code run through takes about 5-8 hours to run. Would running them two at a time or all at once cause any problems?

They are each self contained and are pulling no outside information so there wouldn't be a problem with them trying to access the same outside information at the same time.

#### Edit:

Each Access program would be running code in VBA that essentially compares the stored latitude and longitude locations of devices (MIUs) to a set of grid points and groups all MIUs in said grid in a new table. The grid is shifted after this process and repeated until the maximum latitude and longitudes for the entire search grid have been reached.

Comment: It very much depends what you are doing...

Comment: @Rich B your edits were not "cleaning up" as you call them simply your desire to have your name on everything just like when you keep on changing I'm to I am in all of my posts.

Comment: @Jan&RichB. This is a site to get help. If you're asking a question you are trying to learn. Downvoting someone just because they asked a question that you feel is ignorant is just plain counter-productive. If someone IS ignorant then they need to learn. If they need to learn they need to be here. You have no idea of the constraints of the problem. Many people have limited resources and use Access to cover the gap. There is nothing unreasonable about the question. And responses that amount to "You're dumb for asking" really only reflect personally on you. You should retract your vote. Not OK

Comment: I saw no issues wuith Rich B's edits...

Comment: Up-voted because of question snobs.

Comment: **[Insert self-righteous yet misguided anger here]**

Comment: @Rich B: I rolled back your original edits because I saw no added value to them just like I roll back most of your edits to my posts because you insist on doing almost nothing besides removing contractions, colons, and semicolons. Not to mention all the times you've butchered sentences with incorrect edits even changing a city name to something different just because you didn't recognize it. If you'll notice I'm not rolling back the edits this time because there is value added edits.

Comment: @Rich B: Also, How is the source code being ran by the Access instances that I'm mainly asking the question about irrelevant? As I had stated in a previous comment I only added the source code because Mitch Wheat's comment seemed to me to implied the need for it.

Comment: @Rich B: I do understand editing on this site. As a general rule it is a good thing for people to be able to edit peoples posts in order to correct spelling, grammar, technical wording (such as changing the word files to instances), etc. Just like the rollback tool was added so that when people try and fail to "fix" a post, it can easily be corrected. I understand the editing just fine as far as I can tell. Do you understand editing on this site? What in the world do you have against contractions anyway?

Comment: @Rich B: As I've tried to explain to you before, if you want to persuade someone of something try using logic, examples, etc. Making illogical comments with no reasoning even attempted at being given coupled with asinine comments about crying is, to say the least, not a good way anyone decent would try to persuade somebody.

Comment: Yet again asinine comments. I can't help but notice you are never able to back up anything you say with any form of logic or examples. You just try to force your illogical opinions on people thinking that just because you believe it, others should bow down to you.

Comment: It's interesting that RichB should be editing questions for form, when 3 of his 9 questions have been downvoted (one with 7 downvotes!!), plus he already has a peer pressure badge, which means he deleted another question with 4 or more downvotes. That means he has, best case, -14 reputation in asking questions! So don't take comments personally, Bryan, but do try to phrase your questions better in the future.

Comment: @Bryan: If you feel you have been somehow wrong by any edits, please by all means, inform the moderators. Otherwise, I am sorry you feel persecuted.

Comment: @Dervin Thunk: I'm not taking them personally at all I just get frustrated with people who refuse to use logic and resort to stating an opinion and then call people names for disagreeing with them. In the end it always seems to end up with them refuse to see logic that's right in front of them. Basically they close their eyes, state that a chair is yellow, and refuse to accept any information that opposes their view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a "who knows?" type of question.  If the 5 - 8 hour process is consuming either most of the CPU cycles or most of the RAM  then running two processes on the box won't improve speed; it would actually degrade it due to task switching reasons.

If those processes are truly independent, you might consider having multiple machines work on different copies of the database.  That way you could scale out.

Of course, I'm not sure what the process does so it's hard to say whether this is viable or not.

Comment: I just checked and just running one takes up around 50% cpu usage so I'll try to get one running on another persons computer like you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As many know, I'm a big promoter of Access. In this case, it seems to me that Access is probably not the right tool.

But I'm assuming you've implemented your process in Access in the most logical possible way. For instance, if you could replace walking a recordset and updating a field/fields in each row with a SQL Update, that would likely be vastly more efficient.

One thing to consider is that many people often walk a set of records making updates when they could probably slice the problem vertically and issue a finite number of SQL statements (one for each column). An example of this would be when you are trying to synchronize the data between two indentical tables that have both been updated. It's much more efficient to write on-the-fly SQL Updates that go column-by-column than it is to walk row-by-row and updating field-by-field.

The performance improvement from such a re-design can be more than one order of magnitude.

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding what you mean or how I could implement it. What my Access code is basically doing is searching through an entire cities worth of grid points (each of the grid points are 60ft apart) by 250ft by 250ft grid increments and grouping the results in new separate tables. If I understand correctly, then your saying instead of making new tables I should add a few columns to my core tables that I'm getting my info from and add information to group them correctly the same as I'm doing with the new tables and that it'll be faster that way. Did I get that all right?

Comment: I'm not saying anything of the sort. I'm suggesting that you might be better off using a database back end that has data types for this (i.e.,. geographic data types). I'm suggesting that whatever back end you have, Access might not be the most efficient coding environment for manipulating your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 2 different **instances** of Access then this will depend more on what you are doing and the capacity of the computer (RAM and Processor Speed, Number of Processors).

I find if I am importing larges amounts of data and move the focus away from access, when I try to switch back the application may stop responding.

You can always try with a test run...

When I have a large job to run I do it on our Citrix server.

It is a good idea to have a progress meter running so you can check the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have found starting MS Access in parallel from a .CMD file:

start  db1.accdb   /x macro1
start  db2.accdb   /x macro2
start  db3.accdb   /x macro3
start  db4.accdb   /x macro4

Has issues.  MS gives the appearance of starting all 4 DB's and closing when complete.  These processes are completely independent looking at different databases.  The problem is MS will close one prematurely without warning (added an update timestamp to result set for validation).  Perhaps there is a way to segregate the memory space?